# Parsing POST data with body-parser in Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

I am trying to build a simple Node.js app which will parse data passed to it as POST requests from my AngularJS app. Below is the code used in my AngularJS app and my Node.js app. Problem I am facing is that I've searched the web trying to find how to parse (data and header) information passed in POST requests but failed to find any example, so any help with an example of parsing (data and header) passed in POST requests will help me a lot. Thanks.

Note: I am using express 4.1.2, body-parser 1.8.0.

Node app:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(200);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

POST request code

```
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          var dataObj = {};
          dataObj.name = 'Chan';
          dataObj.email_address = 'email@domain.com';

          var myToken = '1234567890';

          $http({ method:'POST',                     
                  url: '/',
                  data: dataObj,
                  headers: { 'Token' : myToken
                  }
          }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                deferred.resolve(data);
          }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){ 
                deferred.reject(status);
          });

          return deferred.promise;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting `data` to a plain js object, angular is interpreting that as a urlencoded form with the various keys and values in that object.

So there's two possible fixes here. One is to add something like `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` after `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

The second possible fix is to change your $http call to post JSON instead of urlencoded data. For that, change `data: dataObj,` to `data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),` and add `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` to your `headers` so that it looks like this:

```
headers: {
  'Token' : myToken,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

Comment: Tried the first approach, and tried testing using Chrome Postman but I get undefined when trying to access console.log(req.headers['Token']); can you please help by telling me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: When you POST from angular, do you see the header in the request headers in Chrome's network tab?

Comment: Yes, I found the issue for header, I should have used req.headers['token'] instead of req.headers['Token']. What I can't found out how to access till now is data being sent. Tried accessing them using req.body.name or req.body.email_address but with no luck. Any thoughts on accessing data? Thanks